# protect SQL injection on laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need to do auto completion on site, I use laravel.
now it work like this:

```
Group:: whereRaw( where lower (name) like lower ('$q%'))->get ()
```

But it is not safe
I try do like this:

```
$q="a"; group:: whereRaw("lower (name) like lower ('?%')",[$q])->get ()
```

always return empty array, but

```
$q="a"; group:: whereRaw("lower (name) like lower ('$q%')")->get ()
```

return correct result

Comment: Why do you need to use Raw anyway? `Group::where('name', 'LIKE', $q.'%')->get();`

Comment: @MarkBaker please, tell me about other ways. I need auto completion, how I can do it?

Comment: `Like` is case insensitive, so you don't need to use `lower`.

Comment: This could be done without using a raw query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, LIKE is case insensitive, so you don't need `lower` or raw.

```
Group::where('name', 'LIKE', $q."%")->get();
```

Comment: Yes. This is the proper way to use Laravel's query builder. The first parameter is the column, the second is the operand, and the third is the value that it will encapsulate.

Comment: Just a note: `LIKE` is only case insensitive when using a case insensitive collation (e.g. `utf8_unicode_ci`). If using a case sensitive collation (e.g. `utf8_unicode_cs` or `utf8_bin`), this will not work.